# can not run springboot JPA application with IntelliJ IDEA but can run with STS-Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want to run a springboot application on IntelliJ IDEA,the console says:

```
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: 
You can only annotate one callback method with
jakarta.persistence.PreUpdate in bean class: 
com.shaw.entity.Approve and callback listener: 
com.shaw.listener.ApproveListener
```

IDEA console:
[image: IDEA console]

But I can run application on STS-Eclipse successfully, please tell me if you has any solution.

PS. I cleaned the project in IDEA and rebuild it, but, the application can't run successfully also the code is same because I'm using git.

I use `@PreUpdate` only once in ApproveListener:

[image: ApproveListener java code]

Comment: You could try deleting the .idea folder in your project folder and then try to import it again.